# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in iquery.min.js

Tags: jquery

I am getting the below error on my webpage. How to solve this? This is the link to it http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/index.html

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Nb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.r._evalUrl (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ia (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: jquery.min.js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) . Did you take a look on this error?

Comment: not seeing failed to load resource for jquery.min.js